# retrieving data from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I tried to retrieve data from php but when I run the code it not passing in javascript. It gives an error. Can anyone help?

Javascript

```
function updateCountryFeatures() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getCountryBounds.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            iso3: countryAlpha2Code
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("updateCountryFeatures: " + errorThrown + " " + jqXHR + " " + textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
$executionStartTime = microtime(true);
$countryBorders = json_decode(file_get_contents("libs/php/countries/countries_large.geo.json"), true);
$border = null;
foreach ($countryBorders['features'] as $feature) {
    if ($feature["properties"]["ISO_A3"] ==  $_REQUEST['iso3']) { 
        $border = $feature;
        break;
    }
}
$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['status']['executedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
$output['data'] = $border;
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Please format the question. This is unreadable. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks Also, please provide the error.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Where is `countryAlpha2Code` set? Probably better to use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php than iterating over the full array. Not clear where/what the error is though so these are just guesses/improvements.

Comment: When I run the file it goes to error:function.

Comment: Countryalpha2code is jst variable name